# No such a module 'Firebase' in Tests.swift file after Converting to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, cocoapods

After I converted the project to swift 3 I'm getting this error in Test.swift file:

```
No such module 'Firebase'
Command/usr/bin/ditto failed with code 1
```

is that mean I have to update the firebase framework? Why that happened?

*The application still runs though!

*Here's the pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'TheTestingApp' do
pod 'Firebase' 
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

Comment: its not enough information about the error, but generally application should work because you referred framework, ie binaries, which doesn't depends on Swift version.

Comment: Try updating pods

Comment: @Traveler What else do you want to know about the error?

Comment: @JAck I have updated the pod! Nothing changed!

Comment: did you check framework search path. If not checked find that and use default for that. see on google for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is you are using the mentioned **Cocoapods** for **`TheTestingApp`** only you also need to add these or the **Cocoapods** you wanna use for the **`TheTestingAppTest`**

Also Clean your project : - **`CMD+SHIFT+K`**, Then run `pod install` & then run your app.

Something like this:-

```
use_frameworks!

target 'TheTestingApp' do

    pod 'Firebase' 
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

end

target 'TheTestingAppTests' do

    pod 'Firebase' 
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

end
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `${SRCROOT}/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources` on my Unit Test Target's `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` or `Header Search Paths` fixed it for me.

To add it to the `Header Search Paths`:

1. Go to the Unit Test Target
2. Click **Build Settings** tab
3. Search `Header Search Paths`
4. Double click to trigger input view
5. Paste `${SRCROOT}/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources`
6. Clean and build it again and it should be good to go

Ref: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/16#issuecomment-449701843

Answer (score 2):

I've been using `Firebase` in my personal project and I was able to do my Unit Test but tonight I encountered this annoying error in my new project. While Dravidian's answer is correct, it is a bit incomplete and code is redundant. I wrote a blog about this: http://www.prettyitgirl.com/2017/07/how-to-fix-missing-required-module-in.html and to summarize, here are the steps on how I solved this problem :)

1. Make sure that all your dependencies are targeting Swift 3.0 version and add your test target under your main target, like so:

   ```
   target 'ProjectName' do

     pod 'Firebase/Auth'
     pod 'Firebase/Core'
     pod 'Firebase/Database'
     pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
     pod 'Firebase/Storage'

   target 'ProjectNameTests' do
     inherit! :search_paths
   end

   post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Add a search path in your **Header Search Paths**
   In your Tests target’s Build Settings, search for **Header Search Paths** and add these two new search paths:

   ```
   $(SRCROOT)/Pods (recursive)
   ${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources (non-recursive)
   ```

EZ! :)

Comment: didn't help, though I didn't add `post_install do |installer| ... end` (as I understand this one has nothing to do with this problem, why did you add it here?)

Comment: this helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/40524145/7767664 but replace `Firebase` with `Firebase/*`

Comment: work for me, add to your podfile 
`target 'ProjectNameTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
end`

Answer (score 0):

you check your podfile its already in declare at that time your project has been clean (ctrl+shift+k) Otherwise podfile data erase and again podfile install its should better work..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, being as it is, Xcode sometimes reports misleading errors. There could be a lot of other issues under the hood but in this case, you can't see other issues that are really breaking your code if you don't solve "error" with "No such module 'Firebase'". So, this could be just a mask for real error. All those answers above could resolve your "mask" but you will see exact issue (in the most of cases) after you please this module demand somehow.