# Firebase not downloading pods

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, swift3

When I install 'Firebase' pod, this message comes out and I am not able to work on Xcode.

```
Lopez-MacBook-Pro:tres Lopezeselmejor$ vim Podfile
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'tres' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for tres
 'Firebase'
end

Lopez-MacBook-Pro:tres Lopezeselmejor$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `tres.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total
pods installed.

[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
```

Comment: Markdown is easy. Learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ***Podfile*** to :-

```
use_frameworks!
target 'tres' do

  pod 'Firebase'
end
```

When your terminal is done installing `Firebase` to your app. Close your current ***.xcodeProj*** go to your app folder, you will see a ***.xcworkspace*** file, Open that and do your further coding in there..

**PS:-** In swift3 , you might run into some problems in tests file.. see this :- [No such a module 'Firebase' in Tests.swift file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39569694/6297658)