# Missing required module Firebase - Jenkins build error

Tags: swift, xcode, jenkins, firebase, continuous-integration

I have configured jenkins for building my ios-swift application. i have used
xcode version 8.1 and  swift version 3. I am new to Jenkins and continues integration process. Based on my console output, i think build is successful. bacause console output print like this

```
 Touch build/testinng.app
        cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/build/testinng.app

    CodeSign build/testinng.app
        cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test
        export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

    Signing Identity:     "-"

        /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/build/testinng.app

    ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

    2016-11-09 19:51:39.300 xcodebuild[2659:26623] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (E99CCCC3-8EED-4FBA-8A00-2CD3C0D7273F) Beginning test session testinngUITests-E99CCCC3-8EED-4FBA-8A00-2CD3C0D7273F at 2016-11-09 19:51:39.299 with Xcode 8B62 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7f9dce6bc690> {
            SimDevice: SimDevice : iPhone 7 (223F7310-19DF-4FA7-B147-73AB8B48454F) : state={ Booted } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7 } runtime={ SimRuntime : 10.1 (14B72) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-1 }
    } (10.1 (14B72))
```

But after this console output print failure message.

```
failed to import required module: 'Firebase'.
```

I gofinal console output like this.

```
 Touch build/testinng.app
        cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/build/testinng.app

    CodeSign build/testinng.app
        cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test
        export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

    Signing Identity:     "-"

        /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/build/testinng.app

    ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

    2016-11-09 19:51:39.300 xcodebuild[2659:26623] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (E99CCCC3-8EED-4FBA-8A00-2CD3C0D7273F) Beginning test session testinngUITests-E99CCCC3-8EED-4FBA-8A00-2CD3C0D7273F at 2016-11-09 19:51:39.299 with Xcode 8B62 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7f9dce6bc690> {
            SimDevice: SimDevice : iPhone 7 (223F7310-19DF-4FA7-B147-73AB8B48454F) : state={ Booted } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7 } runtime={ SimRuntime : 10.1 (14B72) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-1 }
    } (10.1 (14B72))


=== BUILD TARGET testinngTests OF PROJECT testinng WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Create product structure
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/build/testinng.app/PlugIns/testinngTests.xctest

ProcessInfoPlistFile build/testinng.app/PlugIns/testinngTests.xctest/Info.plist testinngTests/Info.plist
    cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/testinngTests/Info.plist -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -o /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/build/testinng.app/PlugIns/testinngTests.xctest/Info.plist

CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/testinngTests/testinngTests.swift
    cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/testinngTests/testinngTests.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.1.sdk -I /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/build -F /--akyiibisusqoudfyyfxubyhwzzgz/Build/Intermediates/testinng.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testinngTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/testinngTests.swiftdeps -o /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testinng-akyiibisusqoudfyyfxubyhwzzgz/Build/Intermediates/testinng.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testinngTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/testinngTests.o
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/testinngTests/testinngTests.swift:10:18: error: missing required module 'Firebase'
@testable import testinng
                 ^

2016-11-09 19:51:48.418 xcodebuild[2659:26623] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testinng-akyiibisusqoudfyyfxubyhwzzgz/Logs/Test/B554B7BB-8F73-4B3F-8B9B-B07918ED46AB/Session-testinngUITests-2016-11-09_195139-CXzaIj.log" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testinng-akyiibisusqoudfyyfxubyhwzzgz/Logs/Test/B554B7BB-8F73-4B3F-8B9B-B07918ED46AB/Session-testinngUITests-2016-11-09_195139-CXzaIj.log}
2016-11-09 19:51:48.418 xcodebuild[2659:26623] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testinng-akyiibisusqoudfyyfxubyhwzzgz/Logs/Test/B554B7BB-8F73-4B3F-8B9B-B07918ED46AB/Session-testinngTests-2016-11-09_195139-NdHjC1.log" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testinng-akyiibisusqoudfyyfxubyhwzzgz/Logs/Test/B554B7BB-8F73-4B3F-8B9B-B07918ED46AB/Session-testinngTests-2016-11-09_195139-NdHjC1.log}
2016-11-09 19:51:48.419 xcodebuild[2659:27966] Connection peer refused channel request for "dtxproxy:XCTestManager_IDEInterface:XCTestManager_DaemonConnectionInterface"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7f9dceef3b20>
2016-11-09 19:51:48.419 xcodebuild[2659:26664] Connection peer refused channel request for "dtxproxy:XCTestManager_IDEInterface:XCTestManager_DaemonConnectionInterface"; channel canceled <DTXChannel: 0x7f9dcee7ded0>

Testing failed:
    Missing required module 'Firebase'
** TEST FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/testinng_Bit_Test/testinngTests/testinngTests.swift
(2 failures)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
```

What is the issue related with this?

Comment: I also am facing the same issue. It got my head spinning for the past two days. Searched whole internet, SO, google everywhere. Applied all proposed solutions. But didn't succeeded. I expect someone with deeper knowledge can help solve this issue.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After an extensive research, I finally found a solution for this problem.
The second modification I did in the `Runpath Search Paths` is I believe actually solved this problem. Below are the things I did/modified.

1.I moved pod 'Firebase' to my test target in the pod file as shown below.:

```
 target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase'
end
```

2.configure`Runpath Search Paths` to point to `$(FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS)`

3.In addition to all the above, I uninstalled my old cocoapod(1.0.2) and installed latest version (1.1.1), removed Firebase, reinstalled it.. Then `pod install` and `pod updated` in terminal.

Comment: great! but don't use `pod 'Firebase'`, use `pod 'Firebase/Core'` and so on `pod 'Firebase/*' `

Comment: can confirm. adding an additional test target fixes the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so your unit test step is failing.  It looks like there may be a networking issue.  It's hard to tell exactly what's going on just from the console output.  There's a lot of variance when it comes to the environment for Jenkins servers.  It's always good to look at the logs that Jenkins points to when a problem occurs.

Look at the lines below `@testable import testinng`.  They point you to some logs.

If you're looking to get your Jenkins job to work immediately, then you can always skip running the unit tests for now and come back to fixing that part in the future.  There is risk associated with this, but if you are looking to fix your job ASAP, then this is probably the route to go if you can't debug the issue quickly enough.

It's hard to say EXACTLY how to fix your problem without looking at the logs or at least getting a little more context, but I would suggest not sharing your logs.

Comment: i didnt add unit testing in jenkins post build action. But in the time of project creation, i have selected unit testing option on xcode ide.